# Error in Proof: Why is the lower box dimension not finitely stable?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, solution-verification, fractals

**Main Theme of the Question:** I read (and proved) that the upper box dimension is finitely stable. I think we can mimic the same proof for the lower box dimension, but it is explicitly stated (in Falconer's Fractal Geometry) that the lower box dimension is not finitely stable. I write this post to seek help in finding the flaw in my proof. For a brief word on notation, please skip to the end of the post. If you're interested, please continue reading.

---

**Proof of Finite Stability of Upper Box Dimension:**

$\overline\dim_B F$ is finitely stable, i.e. $\overline \dim_B (E\cup F) = \max\{\overline\dim_B E, \overline\dim_B F\}$. To see this, we prove $\le$ and $\ge$ inequalities.

1. Since $E\subset E\cup F$ and $F\subset E\cup F$, it is clear that $\overline\dim_B E \le \overline \dim_B (E\cup F)$ and $\overline\dim_B E \le \overline \dim_B (E\cup F)$, hence $\max\{\overline\dim_B E, \overline\dim_B F\} \le \overline \dim_B (E\cup F)$.
2. Note that $N_\delta(E\cup F) \le N_\delta(E) + N_\delta(F) \le 2\max\{N_\delta(E), N_\delta(F)\}$. Taking logarithm on both sides, interchanging $\max$ and $\log$ on RHS (because $\log$ is a strictly increasing function), and dividing throughout by $-\log\delta$, we get
   $$\frac{\log N_\delta(E\cup F)}{-\log\delta} \le \frac{\log 2}{-\log\delta} + \max\left\{\frac{\log N_\delta(E)}{-\log\delta},\frac{\log N_\delta(F)}{-\log\delta} \right\}$$
   Taking $\delta\to 0$, we get $\overline\dim_B(E\cup F)\le \max\{\overline\dim_B E, \overline\dim_B F\}$.

---

**Question:** Why can't we repeat exactly the same proof for $\underline\dim_B F$, taking $\underline\lim_{\delta\to 0}$ in place of $\overline\lim_{\delta\to 0}$ everywhere? Am I missing something subtle, that disallows us from taking $\underline\lim_{\delta\to 0}$ in one (or more) of the inequalities? I'm not able to see this, and I'd appreciate any help.

Since $E\subset E\cup F$ and $F\subset E\cup F$, $\underline\dim_B E \le \underline \dim_B (E\cup F)$ and $\underline\dim_B E \le \underline \dim_B (E\cup F)$ still hold. Hence $\max\{\underline\dim_B E, \underline\dim_B F\} \le \underline \dim_B (E\cup F)$ must also continue to hold. My sense is that something is going wrong while taking limits (or maybe somewhere else) in the other direction of the inequality, i.e. $\underline\dim_B(E\cup F)\le \max\{\underline\dim_B E, \underline\dim_B F\}$ must not hold.

---

**Notation:**

1. $\overline\dim_B F$,  $\underline\dim_B F$ and  $\dim_B F$:

> The lower and upper box-counting dimensions of a subset $F$ of $ℝ^n$ are given by
> $$\color{blue}{\underline{\dim}_B F = \underline{\lim}_{\delta\to 0} \frac{\log N_\delta(F)}{-\log \delta}}$$
> $$\color{blue}{\overline{\dim}_B F = \overline{\lim}_{\delta\to 0} \frac{\log N_\delta(F)}{-\log \delta}}$$
> and the box-counting dimension of $F$ by
> $$\color{blue}{\dim_B F = \lim_{\delta\to 0} \frac{\log N_\delta(F)}{-\log \delta}}$$
> (if this limit exists), where $N_\delta(F)$ is the smallest number of sets of diameter at most $$ that cover $F$.

2. What is  $\underline{\lim}_{\delta\to 0}$ and $\overline{\lim}_{\delta\to 0}$?

> $$\color{blue}{\underline{\lim}_{x\to 0} f(x) = \lim_{r\to 0} \inf\{f(x) : 0 < x < r\}}$$
> $$\color{blue}{\overline{\lim}_{x\to 0} f(x) = \lim_{r\to 0} \sup\{f(x) : 0 < x < r\}}$$

---

**Related questions on this site:** (these do not answer my question - my question is very specific to understanding the flaw in my proposed proof, which mimics the corresponding proof for upper box dimension).
[(a) How can I find an example to illustrate that the lower box dimension may not be finitely stable?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2278956/how-can-i-find-an-example-to-illustrate-that-the-lower-box-dimension-may-not-be)

[(b) Lower Box Dimension Inequality [duplicate]](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2318657/lower-box-dimension-inequality?noredirect=1&lq=1) 
[(c) Simple counter example to show box-dimension is not finitely stable? [duplicate]](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2524062/simple-counter-example-to-show-box-dimension-is-not-finitely-stable?noredirect=1&lq=1)

---

**References:**
Fractal Geometry, Kenneth Falconer.

Thank you!

Comment: One of the questions to which you have linked gives an explicit example of "why" you can't just replace the limit superior with a limit inferior in the proof and expect things to work out:  the result simply isn't true.  The key insight might be to remember that the limit superior deals with suprema, and taking a supremum over a larger set gives things "more room" to get large ($E \subseteq F \implies \sup(E) \le \sup(F)$).  On the other hand, taking an infimum over a larger set gives things "more room" to get small ($E \subseteq F \implies \inf(E) \ge \inf(F)$).

Comment: In short, swapping an infimum for a supremum will reverse the direction of inequalities.

Comment: @XanderHenderson Thanks for the clarification, I understand it now! Please feel free to add this as an answer (even if it's short).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the sake of completeness, I am adding an answer based on @XanderHenderson's comments. In general, if $E$ and $F$ are two subsets of $\mathbb R^n$ (or whatever space), and $E\subset F$, then
$$\sup(E) \le \sup(F)$$
and
$$\inf(E) \ge \inf(F)$$
The upper box dimension is finitely stable since taking supremum on both sides preserves the inequality, while taking infimum reverses it (hence the lower box dimension is not finitely stable).